# Scheduling a tournament with $N$ teams

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, integer-programming, operations-research, binary-programming

I want to make a "good" schedule for a tournament between $N$ teams. Using memories from my (long gone) student days, I expressed it as a binary integer program. With the current set of constraints, and $N=10$, the resulting program has about $11,000$ variables and $20,000$ constraints. Is this considered large nowadays? The GLPK solver finds an optimal solution in about $20$ minutes, which is great.

But now I wonder if I could speed things up a bit. In particular, if I try to add some constraints, the solver sometimes takes much, much more time.

What tools or techniques can I use?

I can give a detailed description of the problem (or even show code), if that helps.

Comment: Yes, the code would be nice.

Comment: What makes a "good" schedule?

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo The code is here: https://github.com/saffroy/tournament_ilp/blob/master/tournament_ilp.py#L10

Comment: @S.Y I gave more details in the link to the code above. A "good" schedule fits a number of constraints, such as "a team plays each opponent twice" or "a team is in a single place on a given day", and minimizes the number of days to complete the schedule.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo I notice that you changed the title of the question, such that the focus is now more on the base problem (scheduling the tournament, for which I do have a solution) rather than speeding up the computation of the solution (which is my main motivation in asking here). Do you think the specific problem matters much in how one can speed up the solution?

Answer (score 0):

It would be interesting to see your code. I think you may have too many variables.

An IP is a good way to solve this problem.

Let there be $N$ teams and $M$ rounds.

I would choose my variables to take the form $PLAY_{ijk}$ for $1\le i \le N$, $1\le j \le N$ and $1\le k \le M$.

$PLAY_{ijk}=1$ if team $i$ plays team $j$ in round $k$ and $PLAY_{ijk}=0$ otherwise.

The number of these variables is $N^2M$.

Constraints are:

$PLAY_{iik}=0$ (never play against yourself): $N$ constraints

$\Sigma_{j} PLAY_{ijk}\le 1$ (never play more than one other team in any given round): $NM$ constraints

$\Sigma_{i} PLAY_{ijk}\le 1$ (never play more than one other team in any given round): $NM$ constraints

$\Sigma_{k} PLAY_{ijk}\le 1$ (once a pair of teams have played each other they can never meet in a later round): $N^2$ constraints

Use the variables $ROUNDPLAYED_k$ for $1 \le k \le M$ to see if any games are played in a particular round.

$ROUNDPLAYED_k=1$ if some games have been played in round $k$ and $ROUNDPLAYED_k=0$ otherwise.

The number of these variables is $M$.

Constraints:

$ROUNDPLAYED_k \ge \frac{\Sigma_{ij} PLAY_{ijk}}{N^2}$

(this forces $ROUNDPLAYED_k$ to be larger than $0$ if even one match is played in the $k$th round, but keeps the value less than $1$. Because this is an IP, that sets $ROUNDPLAYED_k$ to 1).

You want to play as few rounds as possible, so the objective function is given by:

Minimise $\Sigma_k ROUNDPLAYED_k$

Comment: My approach is very similar to yours. I have more variables because the problem I tried to solve is more complex: it deals with teams gathering at specific places (at most one in a day) to play opponents. The code is here: https://github.com/saffroy/tournament_ilp/blob/master/tournament_ilp.py#L10